# Is there an OS independent URL file?

Tags: windows, .desktop, symbolic-link, url

I'm sure you know the .lnk or .url files from Windows that can be used to launch your browser with a given target website. In Ubuntu, I know there are .desktop files, but I personally feel like they're overcomplicated, and obviously, they don't work on Windows. Is there any OS independent file that just opens a URL?

Comment: How is this question about Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, there is not any OS-independent file that just opens a URL.

The reason for this is **context** - how does the OS know the file contains a URL?

As you've already mentioned, files with `.lnk` and `.url` extensions are treated as links by Windows.  But that's only because Microsoft decided to process files with those extensions in that manner.  Without that OS-level rule, those URL files are functionally identical to thousands of other files on your computer.

File extensions (the stuff that comes after the last `.` in a filename) were implemented as an early form of metadata; a way for a filename to indicate the file's contents.  Some examples of frequently-seen extensions: `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, and `.gif`.

These sample extensions are all "image" extensions - they are all used with image files.  If I renamed an existing image file from `profile.png` to `profile`, the contents of the file do not change, but Windows will no longer treat the file as an "image" file. This is true for all major operating systems.

*Note: I intentionally used the term "operating systems", although "graphical user interfaces" would be more accurate. For many, the GUI is synonymous with the OS.  While they are closely linked, they are not the same.*

All of this is to say: without some **context** (eg the file extension), the OS doesn't know how to interpret the contents of a file.

In order to create an "OS-independent file that just opens a URL", the assorted developers for the major operating systems would need to standardize on a filename format (eg always use the `.url` extension) or some other way to indicate "this file contains a URL".  While this sounds good on the surface, history has shown that such solutions end up being restrictive and create unintended issues in the long term.  (One of my favorite "unintended long-term" examples: [What are the Windows A: and B: drives used for?](https://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for))